# Strange result of StratifiedShuffleSplit

Tags: python, pandas

When I drop some rows before stratification procedure I receive strange result

Machine learning. I need to investigate ML results on groups of data

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

def stratifid(df, target, test_sz = 0.2):
 split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size  = test_sz, random_state = 42)
 for tr_idx, te_idx in split.split(df, df[target]):
   train = df.loc[tr_idx]
   test  = df.loc[te_idx]
 return train, test

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'gender' :      [1,  1,  0, 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, ],
    'age' :         [13, 45, 1, 45, 15, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15],
    'cholesterol' : [1,  2,  2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'smoke' :       [0,  0,  1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 4, 4, 2]},
     dtype = np.int64)

df1 = df.loc[df['age'] > 13]

X_train, X_test = stratifid(df1, ['gender'], 0.2)
print(X_train)

I expect correct stratification for data. But my output is following:
   gender   age  cholesterol  smoke
0     NaN   NaN          NaN    NaN
4     1.0  15.0          1.0    7.0
1     1.0  45.0          2.0    0.0
6     0.0  16.0          1.0    3.0
3     1.0  45.0          1.0    1.0
7     0.0  16.0          1.0    4.0

Nan values are not expected ones....
If I make stratification for whole df( when df1 = df) all are Ok. What I'm doing wrong?
```

Comment: Once you removed few rows based on some specific criteria and store it into new data frame, your new data frame still hold the same index. When you pass this data frame for stratification it consider the missing index for example index 0, which is not present in new data frame (remove as per age filter) and therefore replaced it with NaN. Reset index using df1.reset_index(inplace=True) del df1['index'] and then pass for stratification.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def stratifid(df, target, test_sz = 0.2):
 split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size  = test_sz, random_state = 42)
 for tr_idx, te_idx in split.split(df, df[target]):
   train = df.loc[tr_idx]
   test  = df.loc[te_idx]
 return train, test

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'gender' :      [1,  1,  0, 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, ],
    'age' :         [13, 45, 1, 45, 15, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15],
    'cholesterol' : [1,  2,  2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'smoke' :       [0,  0,  1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 4, 4, 2]},
     dtype = np.int64)

df1 = df.loc[df['age'] > 13]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
del df1['index']

X_train, X_test = stratifid(df1, ['gender'], 0.2)
print(X_train)
```